# Fixed CSS Footer to floating / Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a fixed bar at the bottom of my web page. In that bar the are a few buttons that contain commonly accessed pages on the site.
I have a footer that sits at the bottom of the page.
What I would like to do is, as you scroll down the page, when you get to the bottom of the main content, I want the fixed bar to scroll up and show the footer below it.
What is the best way of achieving this?
Below is an example. Red represents the entire page. Blue represents the visible portion of the page. Yellow is the fixed bar. Grey is the footer. Once you scroll to the end of the main content on the page the yellow fixed bar will scroll up and the footer will appear below. My page is set up like this:

```
<div id="red">
    <div id="blue"></div>
    <div id="yellow"></div>
    <footer></footer>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? if yes, kindly show us your code.

Comment: Your Question isn't clear. Please Provide HTML to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here Is the solution Using `Jquery`:

bind [`.scroll()`](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/)  to `$(document)` element & check whether `OnScroll` The `ScrollTop` reaches the 
end of The `window` element here in this case `top` of your `footer` element.

and then `animate` your `fixed_element` to show the hidden `foot` element beneath it.

so here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Demo</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script><!-- Include Jquery -->
<script type="text/javascript">
/* Code to Handle Scroll */
$(document).ready(function(){
    var hgh=$(".foot").height();
    $(document).scroll(function(){
// Check Whether End Point is reached or not.
       if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('.foot').offset().top + $('.foot').height() - window.innerHeight) {
           $(".fixed_bar").animate({
               "position":"fixed",
               "bottom":""+hgh+"",
               "right":"0px"
           },100); // I'll Suggest to Use .fadeOut("100"); Here
     }
        else
        {
            $(".fixed_bar").animate({
               "position":"fixed",
               "bottom":"0px",
               "right":"0px"
           },100);  // I'll Suggest to Use .fadeIn("100"); Here

        }
    });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.fixed_bar{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:25px;
    display:block;
    background:#a77;
    text-align:center;
    color:#ddeeff;
}

body{
    margin:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.foot{
width:100%;
    height:25px;
    display:block;
    background:#c33;
    color:yellow;
    text-align:center;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<center><h2>
o<br /><hr />
t<br /><hr />
h<br /><hr />
e<br /><hr />
r<br /><hr />
<br /><hr />
c<br /><hr />
o<br /><hr />
n<br /><hr />
t<br /><hr />
e<br /><hr />
n<br /><hr />
t<br /><hr />
    <br /><hr /></h2></center>
<div class="foot">Footer</div>
<div class="fixed_bar">Bar Hiding The Footer</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and Here is The Working

## [`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/wy8Fs/)

For the same.

Hope it'll help you. Cheers :).